# how to persist data in edittext when entering the activity through menu option of other activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I have an activity which gets the intent data(string) frm other activity. I want to persist this data and the data(integer) entered by the user in the edittexts. I want to persist all these data when the user enters this activity from the menu option of next activity.

Comment: You've put sharedpreferences as a tag so have you tried to do it that way? that would be a good way? Post some code and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can use `SharedPreference`.

**2.** You can also use a `file`, even a `Database`. SQLite ships with Android.

Comment: How to use sharedpreference and the database for the same? Both the methods. The data(string) to  get persist is the intent data.

Comment: @user1611632 well in SQLite you can always use `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name"));`